# Android: Scanning for TCP socket server IP (Port ist known)

Tags: android, arrays

I'm scanning my subnet for socket servers with port 7 open and using parallel threads. I always see a shot "connect" and "disconnect" on the server side, so the basic code should be OK.

But how do i collect the found (successfully connected) server IPs in an array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
Button buttonConnect;

Socket socket = null;
int port = 7;
int timeout = 200;

final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

}

Button.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String iIPv4 = "192.168.0.1";
        iIPv4 = iIPv4.substring(0, iIPv4.lastIndexOf("."));
        iIPv4 += ".";

        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
            findSocket(es, iIPv4 + i, port, timeout);
        }
    }
};

public static Future<Boolean> findSocket(final ExecutorService es,
        final String ip, final int port, final int timeout) {
    return es.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
                socket.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: So your question isn't about what your title says it is about, it is about a trivial data structure question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then in the `try` block of `findSocket` before `return true;`

```
arayList.add(ip);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the arrayList has always a length / size of 0.

Comment: I had also to add 7s timeout to get this code working. It takes ~30sec. to scan the subnet.